# Writing a file in a directory

Tags: android, file

```
File dir = android.os.Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory();
             file =  new File(dir + File.separator + "Music1.mp3");
             if (!file.exists()) {
                 file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                 file.createNewFile(); 
                }

             fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
             inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

on `file.createNewFile ()` throws an exception:

```
System.err(275): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

How can i solve this Problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can't write in Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory() use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"
```

and the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Why can't you write in `Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()`?

Comment: I think it's for security.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in you Manifest  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Put this in your application's manifest file.

Comment: I have it already installed,I changed it to  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and it worked.